# What tool would be best for getting the max value out of Identical ID rows?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcmap

As the title may imply I want to keep the maximum value in field2 for several identical IDs in field1, the others are deleted for example this table:

```
Field1  Field2
14772   1
14772   4
14766   3
14766   1
14766   1
14766   1
14766   1
14765   1
14765   3
14765   1
```

becomes:

```
Field1  Field2
14772   4
14766   3
14765   3
```

by deleting all the duplicate ID (field1) with lower value in field2. for your information my final objective is to join the table with another using field1, I only want rows with highest field2 value to be joined.

I'm using Arcmap 10.1

Comment: What should happen if the Field2 has is tied for the highest value with an identical Field1 value?

Comment: keep both or delete one of them, one of them should make it through the join process at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000) with the first field being the case field and use the maximum of field 2.

`arcpy.analysis.Statistics(in_tab, out_tab, [['Field2', 'MAX']], 'Field1')`